# How to Display JSON element with js tooltip (angular and BS being used)?

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-ui

Is it possible to show json element in tooltip in JS?

(JSON ELEMENT HERE).tooltip('show');

If yes, how.

I am able to do it for html only with but not with dynamic value from JSON object.

Code :

```
$scope.data = [{'Id':'1','columns ':'name','Observations':'Thompson'},  
           {'Id':'2','columns ':'telephone','Observations':'0145698745'}];

$('#mytable').on('mouseenter','td:nth-child(1)', function(){
    var jsonObj = $scope.data;
    var type;
    $.each(jsonObj,function(i,v){
        if (v.columns == $(this).text()) {
            type = v.Observations;
            console.log(v.Observations);        
            return false;
        }
    })  
    console.log($(this).text());
    $(this).parent().find('tbody.name').tooltip('show'); //WORKS
    (type).tooltip('show'); //DOES NOT WORK                             
});
```

Comment: can you post full code?

Comment: @Bhavikvora I edited the question with full code

Comment: what is `Observations`?

Comment: may be you should change `(type)` to `$(type)` ?

Comment: @teran tried, gives no error but also shows no tooltip on my BS Table.